# Spark type hinting for Column with a specific data type?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Is there a way to specify that a function parameter should be a Column with a specific data type in Spark ?

For example, this dummy example works :

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.Column
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.lit

def addOneYear(myCol: Column): Column = {
    myCol + lit(1)
}
```

But what if I need to specify that myCol should be of Integer data type ?

For example, I would like to write something like that :

```
def addOneYear(myCol: Column[Int]): Column[Int] = {
    myCol + lit(1)
}
```

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Spark [TypedColumn](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/TypedColumn.html), it's available via [Column.as](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/Column.html#as%5BU%5D(implicitevidence$1:org.apache.spark.sql.Encoder%5BU%5D):org.apache.spark.sql.TypedColumn%5BAny,U%5D) and can be used in a limited fashion with [select](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.html#select%5BU1,U2,U3,U4,U5%5D(c1:org.apache.spark.sql.TypedColumn%5BT,U1%5D,c2:org.apache.spark.sql.TypedColumn%5BT,U2%5D,c3:org.apache.spark.sql.TypedColumn%5BT,U3%5D,c4:org.apache.spark.sql.TypedColumn%5BT,U4%5D,c5:org.apache.spark.sql.TypedColumn%5BT,U5%5D):org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset%5B(U1,U2,U3,U4,U5)%5D) to project with.

If you have underlying case classes to work with you may appreciate [frameless](https://github.com/typelevel/frameless) which provides a more typed approach from the outset.

In both cases you'll need to ensure Encoders are available for the field type you are using.